# PHP Secure Log in / Log Out: Log Out Issue

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, logout

I have a PHP login / logout system. The code for the logout is as follows:

```
if($_POST['submit']=='logOut')
{
    setcookie('userName','', time()-60*60*24*100);
    setcookie('login','', time()-60*60*24*100);
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Users are being checked for login status via the following:

```
<?php
if(!$_COOKIE['login']):
// If you are not logged in
?>
```

As far as I can tell, this should log the user out, but it doesn't seem to do so. The site can be viewed at novabvuild.comlu.com, and default login information can be used (admin, admin). This way you folks can see the issue. Login seems to work fine, but the logout doesn't run properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since there are many ways to make an authentication system, I recommend you to explain and maybe put some code here about the login part. I doubt anyone can help you without those details

Comment: the logout could be ok, but it depends how you check if an user is login... if you do it plainly with cookies like it seems from the logout code, that should suffice. What about sessions, anyway? Show us the way you check if an user is logged in.

Comment: @user1397727 I see you edited since answers came in.  Did you try any? did any work?

Comment: I have since discontinued this website, I moved the majority of my code without any major edit to www.msheeksproductions.com on a Bluehost hosting account. I have issues with it still, and the current thread can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689444/login-script-not-executing-bluehost#comment13874148_10689444

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a path:

```
setcookie("userName", "", mktime(12,0,0,1, 1, 1970), "/");
```

You might also get away with: `unset($_COOKIE['cookieName']);`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
unset($_COOKIE[login]) and unset($_COOKIE[userName])
```

OR

```
setcookie("login") and setcookie("userName")
```

Answer (score 0):

used session instead of cookies,
set the session when user login and unset/destroy session when user logout

```
if($_POST['submit']=='logOut')
{
    unset($_SESSION['userName']);
    unset($_SESSION['login']);
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
else if($_POST['submit']=='login')
{
    $_SESSION['userName']=$userName;
    $_SESSION['login']=$login;
}
```

hope this will help you.