# Login Script Not Executing - Bluehost

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication, bluehost

I have the following log in script that is run when a user hits the submit button on the login form on www.msheeksproductions.com. I have removed the DB login info for security reasons.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
        $user = '***************';
        $pass = '***************';
        $host = '***************';
        $data = '***************';
$userN=$_POST['userN'];
$passW=$_POST['passW'];

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db($data)or die("Database Not Found");

$query="SELECT userID FROM sec_login WHERE Username='$userN' AND Password='passW'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$user=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($user==1) {
    session_register("userN");
    header("location: ../index.php");
}
else {
echo("You have entered invalid login information.");
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

My issue is, if you land on the security.php page, nothing happens. The PHP script doesn't seem to be being executed at all. I'm not sure if I have a syntax error somewhere, or if it's a configuration issue with my hosting account. The server is using PHP 5.2. Does anyone know if there are known issues with Bluehost for these sorts of things? If there's a coding error, then obviously I would love to know as well. I'm new to this, so I may not have done everything right.

Also, I am attempting to call the variable again in the index.php file, which seems to not return any data.

```
<?php $usr=$_SESSION['username']; 
echo "User Name Is: $usr"; ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does endif; work in PHP? And you might want to use if (case) { } else { } instead of colons

Comment: First, enable [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to check for syntax. Second, you won't be able to use `header()` where you've got it - move all your PHP to the start of the file.

Comment: @abelito According to Dreamweavers validator, the code is valid. However, I do like the {} syntax better, and since that also validates, I'll use that. Thanks. (This did not, btw, resolve the issue, so please keep the responses coming!)

Comment: @freejosh, I moved the PHP to in front of the DOCTYPE decleration as you suggested, however that had no effect. I also added error reporting, but nothing was generated. Updated code has been edited into the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider the following:

- Beware of SQL injection(Stopped by mysql_real_escape_string);
- Beware of session fixation / hijacking;
- Beware or brute force attacks;
- Please check http://php.net/pdo for better error handling and query parameters....

  ```
  <?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
      $user = '***************';
      $pass = '***************';
      $host = '***************';
      $data = '***************';

      mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect");
      mysql_select_db($data) or die("Database Not Found");

      $result=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sec_login WHERE Username='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' AND Password='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'") or die(mysql_error());

      if(mysql_result($result) == 1) {
          $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
          header("location: ../index.php");
          exit;
      } else {
          $message = 'You have failed to provide valid credentials.';
      }
  } else {
      $message = '<form method="post">
                      <input type="text" name="username" value="username" />
                      <br />
                      <input type="password" name="password" value="password" />
                      <br />
                      <input type="submit" />
                  </form>';
  }
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
          <title>Untitled Document</title>
      </head>

      <body>
          <?php echo $message; ?>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I knew I needed to protect against SQL injection and the like, but had not yet learned the proper process. Also, this seems to work, but when I try to echo out the session variable on the index.php page, it seems to not be set. Or in any case, it doesn't echo anything. Are session variables available across all directories in a given URL? Maybe I'm not calling it properly. I've updated the main post to include the code to call the username variable that I'm using. Thank you!

Comment: Please add session_start(); right after ini_set, now you should be able to output the username..

Comment: That did it! I actually saw your comment after having fixed the problem, but thanks for responding! All pages needed <? session_start() ?> on the first line of code for it to work, but now everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, in case anyone stumbles upon this and needs an example. The following is the code I am now using for a functioning log in script:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $user = '***********';
    $pass = '***********';
    $host = '***********';
    $data = '***********';

    mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect");
    mysql_select_db($data) or die("Database Not Found");

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT userID FROM sec_login WHERE Username='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userN'])."' AND Password='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passW'])."'") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $_SESSION['login']=1;
        $_SESSION['username']=$_POST['userN'];
        $session= session_name() . '=' . session_id();
        header("location: ../index.php?".$session);
        exit();
    } else {
        $message = 'You have failed to provide valid credentials.';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php echo $message; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

connection variables omitted, of course. In order for the other pages to get at the session variables be sure that every page starts with (On literally the first line of code, before even your doctype declaration)

Thanks for you help folks!